# Why doesn't javac produce a warning when using a deprecated constructor of a parameterized type?

Tags: java, javac, java-11

Say you have a parameterized class with a deprecated constructor, and a `User` class that calls this constructor. In the example below, using the diamond operator, javac (version 11.0.11) does not produce a deprecation warning:

```
class DepTester<T> {
    T t;

    @Deprecated
    public DepTester(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}

class User {
    DepTester<String> tester = new DepTester<>("This does not produce a warning!");
}
```

However, with an explicit type argument in the constructor call, the warning is issued:

```
class User {
    DepTester<String> tester = new DepTester<String>("This produces a warning.");
}

[WARNING] DepTester.java:[17,40] DepTester(T) in com.foo.DepTester has been deprecated
```

The explicit type argument is normally not included, which IntelliJ inspection also warns about:

> Explicit type argument String can be replaced with <>

I can't find an explanation for this behaviour in the [Java language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.6). I tried with javac 17, and it produces a warning in both cases, so is this a bug in javac 11?

EDIT: My bug report to Oracle was assigned an ID in the Java bug database: [JDK-8281107](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8281107)

Comment: Your java installation is messed up, or you're on some old version and you have found a bug that is now fixed. I pasted your exact code from the first snippet and it emits a warning about using deprecated API just fine.

Comment: Which jdk version are you using? I am able to reproduce this issue also with jdk 11.0.14 (temurin on mac os).

Comment: javac full version "17.0.1+12" (it's openjdk temurin). Yes, on temurin 11 I don't get the warning. Probably a solved bug then. No warnings on temurin8 either.

Comment: Most projects will remain on jdk 11 for a long time, so I think the fix should be backported. I submitted a bug report to Oracle, and will provide the link if/when the bug is accepted.

Comment: This is extremely non-critical. There's no snowball's chance it'll get backported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You encountered bug [JDK-8257037](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8257037), “No javac warning when calling deprecated constructor with diamond”:

> No deprecation warning is emitted when compiling a class that calls a deprecated constructor when using the diamond syntax to specify the generic types. A deprecation warning is emitted when calling the same constructor using an explicit type argument or a raw type.

It has been fixed with JDK 17.
There’s also a reported [backport to JDK 16](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8257829), but none for earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks! IMO, this should have been backported to the previous LTS release that "everyone" is using. Perhaps it's not considered important enough? We're building a platform with some public Java APIs that has a lot of users, and we want them to be aware that some or our APIs are deprecated for removal.

Comment: I think, a backport to JDK 11 would be useful. But note that you can also use JDK 17 to compile for JDK 11.

Comment: Yes, but that requires all our users to set the `--release` flag, or else they risk getting runtime errors for building with the latest Java APIs. Some or our users still set the `-source/target` flags.

Comment: Since you filed a bug report against JDK 11, there’s some chance that the JDK developers will decide to provide a backport. But even then, it requires your users to update to the fixed JDK version once it’s out.